# Batch file to change power profiles

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

First-time poster here. I'm trying to make a quick script to switch between power-saving and high-performance power modes based on if my laptop is plugged in. I did a bit of googling and came up with [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/run-a-scheduled-task-only-on-battery/0b940588-2915-4e17-b6e3-c51af4cf4c16), and so I tried to modify it to suit my needs. However, there seems to be an issue regarding the IF statement, I can't get it to run for some reason i can't understand. Running the `checker` function by itself works just fine. Happy for any help. Code included below. (For reference, `if OnLine = true`, then the device is plugged into mains)

```
@echo on
call :checker OnLine
if OnLine==true( powercfg /s 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c) else (powercfg /s e2ba9cbc-ad70-403c-8810-530a59af2d53)
pause

:checker 
set OnLine=false
set cmd=WMIC /NameSpace:\\root\WMI Path BatteryStatus Get PowerOnline
%cmd% | find /i "true" > nul && set %~OnLine=true
echo %OnLine%
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: Power schemes have different setting based on if they are running on AC or not. So set your options in your power scheme. There is no need for this. It is a question for superuser.com __How do I start the power applet__ . Choose a power scheme, Edit it, chose Change Advanced Power Settings. Every setting has an AC one and a DC one.

Comment: @Mark It could also be that OP just wants to learn batch scripting and trying something like this is a rather good learning curve

Comment: Not if s/he is imposing c/vb/jscript/etc structured programming concepts into a user batch system. S/he (although it is a pieman) is learning how NOT to write batch.

Comment: @Mark For the power scheme advanced settings, rather than changing any of those I need to change the power profile itself, as my laptop seems to only activate the discrete GPU in high-performance mode. I also wanted to have a crack at batch scripting to just automate some basic tasks, as i really haven't tried batch before, and said why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues like missing spaces between true and the opening parenthesis and the fact that you did not use the variable names with `%` but regardless, even if we fix them it would not work because no value ever gets assigned to the variable.

This should do what you want.

```
@echo off
WMIC /NameSpace:\\root\WMI Path BatteryStatus Get PowerOnline | findstr /i "TRUE" >nul && (echo powercfg /s 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c & echo online)
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (echo powercfg /s e2ba9cbc-ad70-403c-8810-530a59af2d53 & echo OffLine)
```

This is a slightly longer version of the solution should you want to `echo` Online or offline.

```
WMIC /NameSpace:\\root\WMI Path BatteryStatus Get PowerOnline | findstr /I "TRUE"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
        echo Online
        powercfg /s 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
      ) else (
        echo Offline
        powercfg /s e2ba9cbc-ad70-403c-8810-530a59af2d53
  )
```

and just to show you what your solution looks like after it was fixed:

```
@echo off
set onLine=
set mycmd=WMIC /NameSpace:\\root\WMI Path BatteryStatus Get PowerOnline
%mycmd% | findstr /i "TRUE"> nul && set onLine=true
echo %onLine%
if "%onLine%" == "true" (
      powercfg /s 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
    ) else (
      powercfg /s e2ba9cbc-ad70-403c-8810-530a59af2d53
)
exit /B 0
```

To understand the above commands better, open `cmd` and type the following to read their help files.

```
for /?
if /?
findstr /?
```

Comment: Trying the initial shorter solution didn't seem to lend any results, however, the slightly longer and the much longer variants both worked. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Please copy the short one as is now and feedback the results on screen.

Comment: Unsure what you mean about feedback, the file runs however the CMD window simply closes almost instantly. The power performance mode does not change however, either plugged-in or not.

Comment: I changed it so it would not change anything, it should just display on screen. Please just add `pause` at the bottom of the script and show me the output when you ran it.

Comment: After running the script with pause it simply echoed the power modes to me, rather than putting them in place. After i removed the echos from before the powercfg's, it worked completly right. Code (hopefully) shown with the echo's bolded below.

 ```@echo off
WMIC /NameSpace:\\root\WMI Path BatteryStatus Get PowerOnline | findstr /i "TRUE" >nul && (``` **echo** ```powercfg /s 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c & echo online)
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (``` **echo** ```powercfg /s e2ba9cbc-ad70-403c-8810-530a59af2d53 & echo OffLine)```

Comment: Yes. So the echos were simply to display the commands instead of running it so we can verify it works.